# How can I remove duplicates from a multicolumn combobox in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Basically right now I have a combobox, and if I make a simple query, I only get blanks for some reason. I need to grab both `ID` and the field I want and then set the bound column to 2 in order for the data to show up in the combobox.

The problem is, this makes `SELECT DISTINCT` not work, as each field will have a different `ID`, although the field I want has several dup values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ESP_PGPI.ID, ESP_PGPI.Identificacao 
FROM ESP_PGPI 
WHERE (((ESP_PGPI.Identificacao) Is Not Null)) 
ORDER BY ESP_PGPI.Identificacao;
```

This is what I am using right now. If I don't select `ID` as well, I only get blanks.

I have one of two questions needing an answer:

1. Is it possible to only grab the Second Field to populate my
   combobox?
2. If not, is there anyway to remove duplicates?

Best regards,

Francisco

Comment: Simply by looking at a query we cannot tell what data results or its source. Please post some data for [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to remove ID from the combobox's row source:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Identificacao 
FROM ESP_PGPI 
WHERE Identificacao Is Not Null 
ORDER BY 1
```

(this code will work fine),

& you'll need to change how you're using whatever is selected in the combobox;

For example if you've currently got a bit of code like

```
SELECT some_column, ... 
FROM some_table 
WHERE ESP_PGPI_ID = [combobox],
```

you'll need to change this to be:

```
SELECT some_column, ...
FROM some_table INNER JOIN ESP_PGPI ON some_table.ESP_PGPI_ID = ESP_PGPI.ID
WHERE ESP_PGPI.Identificacao = [combobox]
```

Comment: I understand the first part, but where exactly would the code from the second part go?

Comment: And if I used the first part, I am only getting blanks

Comment: @FranciscoPlácido - please post some data so we can help! How do we know what the data outputs. Otherwise, we have to take your word for it or run speculative queries.

Comment: but what kind of data would you like be to put, sorry If I dont understand. Should I post a screenshot of my MS Access with the blanks?

Answer (score 0):

"Hi,

Try using the below code to remove the duplicates

```
SELECT DISTINCT ESP_PGPI.ID, ESP_PGPI.Identificacao 
FROM ESP_PGPI 
WHERE Nz(ESP_PGPI.Identificacao, """") <> """"
ORDER BY ESP_PGPI.Identificacao;
```

Or follow the below steps

We want to eliminate any duplicates from displayed in the combo box.
·

1. Open the form in design view. Then right-click on the combo box and select properties from the popup menu
2. Then click on the button to the right of the row source property to bring up the query builder window
3. In the query builder window position over an area to the right of the table and click on the left mouse button. This will switch the focus to the main query. (so that when you view the Properties window, it displays the properties for the query and not one of the fields)
4. When the query properties window appears, set the unique values property to yes
5. Next close the query builder window and we will be prompted to save the changes. 
   "